# Python, Postgresql trouble copying from csv

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am doing this all as a test. I want to take a csv file that has headers and copy the values into a postgresql database table. The tables columns are named the same as the headers in csv file case-sensitive. table has two columns "pkey", "m". the csv just has the "m" for header. pkey is just the primary key setup to auto increment. As a test i just want to copy the "m" column in the csv file the table.

```
import csv
import psycopg2


database = psycopg2.connect ( database = "testing", user="**", 
password="**", host="**", port="**")

ocsvf = open("sample.csv")

def merger(conn, table_name, file_object):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.copy_from(file_object, table_name, sep=',', columns=('mls'))
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()

try:
    merger(database, 'tests', ocsvf)
finally:
    database.close()
```

when i try to run the code i get this as a error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csvtest.py", line 26, in <module>
merger(database, 'tests', ocsvf)
  File "csvtest.py", line 21, in merger
cursor.copy_from(file_object, table_name, sep=',', columns=('m'))
  psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "m" of relation "tests" does not exist
```

I am sure its something simple that i just keep over looking but i have also googled this and the one thing i found was someone said it might be the primary key is setup right but i tested it and the primary keys works fine when i do manual input from pgadmin. any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
cursor.copy_from(file_object, table_name, sep=',', columns=('mls'))
```

The `('mls')` evaluated to `"mls"` which eventually means that iterating over it will result in 3 items `['m','l','s']`.
You should write this line as follows:

```
cursor.copy_from(file_object, table_name, sep=',', columns=('mls',))
```

The expression `('mls',)` evaluated to a tuple with one item: `"mls"`, which is what I guess you meant to do.

Comment: that was it thanks. i didnt know it would iterate. thank you very much